# how do I convert this python code in python function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I was use threading Pool for my script. I have working code for html table to json conversion.

I am using pandas for html table to json.

```
html_source2 = str(html_source1)

pool = ThreadPool(4) 

table = pd.read_html(html_source2)[0]
table= table.loc[:,~table.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
d = (table.to_dict('records'))
print(json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=False))
results = (json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=False))
```

i want something like:

```
html_source2 = str(html_source1)

pool = ThreadPool(4) 

def abcd():
  table = pd.read_html(html_source2)[0]
  table= table.loc[:,~table.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
  d = (table.to_dict('records'))
  print(json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=False))
  results = (json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? When converting to function.

Comment: since  i am new python, i dont knw how do i convert it to function.

Comment: I don't understand, can't you just add an argument to the `abcd()` function i.e. `def abcd(html_str):` and have it `return results`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to make the function take an input argument, here `html_str` and then have it return the results you need so you can use them outside the function.

```
html_source2 = str(html_source1)

pool = ThreadPool(4) 

def abcd(html_str):
    table = pd.read_html(html_str)[0]
    table= table.loc[:,~table.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
    d = (table.to_dict('records'))
    print(json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=False))
    results = (json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=False))
    return results 

my_results = abcd(html_source2)
```

And remove the `print` call if you don't need to see the output in the function

Comment: how can i use Pool to this?

Comment: What do you mean? Your example code has one input string, you wouldn't need a pool for that. If you show more code, and try to explain what the purpose of threading is, then I can help.

Comment: i want improve speed of executing,for that i want to use multithreading.

Comment: You aren’t going to speed up a single function call by multithreading it. That’s not how it works. Also in python multithreading is only really going to help with I/O bound tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't know much about functions, parameters and how to call functions read here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Consider reading it it's a short read.